# Custom Django admin: unable to assign users to a group because of field rendering

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm currently working on a Django app on which I have created a custom admin section (i know of the existing default admin section, but could not use it).
The "admin" of the website should be able to CRUD users and assign them to a group (either "admin" or "manager" group).
I'm having difficulties upon CRUD users on assigning them to either group, because the rendering of the group field. I have to highlight the group I want to put the user in, but upon saving the user is not assigned to the group chosen. I'm guessing I will have to put this field in some sort of widget but I'm unable to find the solution.

Hereunder the code

forms.py

```
class AdminUserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    """UserCreateForm custom made class"""

    class Meta:
        """ Meta definitioon of UserCreateForm"""

        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'last_name',
            'first_name',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            'email',
            'is_staff',
            'is_active',
            'is_superuser',
            'groups',
        ]
```

views.py (just a create use view here for example)

```
@group_required('Administrator')
def admin_create_user(request): 
    if request.method == "POST":  
        admin_user_create_form = AdminUserCreateForm(request.POST)    
        if admin_user_create_form.is_valid():  
            admin_user_create_form.save()
            if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['Administrator']).exists(): 
                return redirect('admin_home')
            else:
                return redirect('manager_home')   
    else:  
        admin_user_create_form = AdminUserCreateForm()  

    context = {
        'admin_user_create_form': admin_user_create_form,
    }
    return render(request,'admin_create_user.html', context)
```

template

```
<!-- template admin_create_user.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load has_group %}
{% block title %} (ADMIN) Create User {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method ="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<p>{{admin_user_create_form|crispy}}</p>
<p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Users</button></p>
</form>
{% if request.user|has_group:"Administrator" %} 
<a href="{% url 'admin_home' %}" class="btn btn-primary">BACK TO ADMINISTRATOR HOME</a>
{% else %}
<a href="{% url 'manager_home' %}" class="btn btn-primary">BACK TO MANAGER HOME</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock  %}
```

result

[group field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJq0q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not adding the users to the groups. Inorder to do that, first you have to import Group table and add the instance of user which is saved. After doing this your views.py should be like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
@group_required('Administrator')
def admin_create_user(request): 
if request.method == "POST":  
    admin_user_create_form = AdminUserCreateForm(request.POST)    
    if admin_user_create_form.is_valid():
        group = request.POST.get('groups')  
        admin_user_create_form.save()
        admin_user_create_form.groups.add(group) #group must be an instance of your group ie, admin/manager
        if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['Administrator']).exists(): 
            return redirect('admin_home')
        else:
            return redirect('manager_home')   
else:  
    admin_user_create_form = AdminUserCreateForm()  

context = {
    'admin_user_create_form': admin_user_create_form,
}
return render(request,'admin_create_user.html', context)
```

Comment: That did in fact solve it. Thanks!